# How to retrieve items from Firebase Collection in the order of addition (AngularFire 5)?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I need users to display in my `UsersListComponent` in the order in which they were added to Firebase.

At the moment if I add new user, he may appear in the middle of the list, but I want new users to appear at the end of the list.

How can I implement it with AngularFire 5?

My `UsersService` and `UsersListComponent`:

```
export class UsersService {

  usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  users: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(private firebase: AngularFirestore) {
    this.usersCollection = firebase.collection('users');
    this.users = this.usersCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
   }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.users;
  }
```

---

```
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit {

  users: User[];

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to change this method and add sorting there, or using orderby method on fire store as https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

```
this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
  this.users = users.sort((x,y) => x.? - y.?);
});
```

But that is not enough, you need to add a Date to your data when storing to firestore, and then sorting by that